# How to enable internet on Arch Linux without DHCP or Network-Manager?

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I have installed Arch Linux on Virtual Box and am now in post installation setup, and I cannot establish my internet connection in order to download files using pacman, ping also does not work.

After reading the Wiki, I tried configuring a static ip for the ethernet interface, set up routing tables, and tried configuring /etc/systemd/network/enp0s3.network. Here are the outputs.

[image: ip addr]

[image: iproute]

Set systemd-networkd according to the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd#Wired_adapter_using_DHCP)

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/network/enp0s3.network
[Match]
Name=enp0s3
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.44/24
Gateway=192.168.4.1
DNS=233.5.5.5

$ systemctl restart systemd-networkd
$ systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

I have set the static IP to be `192.168.4.44` for the network interface and set up routing tables for it, but not completely sure if it is correct.

Before setting these options, I would get `Temporary failure in name resolution` right away. But after, it would take a while, then I would get the error.

I know that we can simply reattach the boot image, chroot from the live media and install the necessary utilities using `pacstrap`. But I want to learn how to do this without tools like DHCP, Network Manager, Netcl, only using `ip` and the tools already installed. So how can I configure my Arch Linux and set up a wired network connection properly?

P.S. The network for Virtual Box is `Attached to: NAT`

Comment: what device has the address 192.168.4.1?

Comment: I thought that is how we define the gateway value

Comment: yes, the gateway IP is the IP address usually of a router - you don't just make it up

Comment: In this case I am in a virtual box, what would the "router" be?

Comment: I have no knowledge of your networking environment - what's the gateway IP if you use DHCP instead of static, also, what is the Virtual Box host OS

Comment: Virtual Box Host OS is Windows. I don't have "DHCP" installed, I am asking how I could do it with static IP address.

Comment: You say *"I don't have "DHCP" installed"* ... I would assume that since the network you've chosen is `Attached to: NAT` that virtual box does the DHCP for that. Either that, or what other options are there for network?

Comment: I see, if DHCP is installed how would I then configure my Arch device to connect to this NAT network?

Comment: It should do so on installation, don't change a thing, and DHCP works

Comment: However, having read the **documentation**, if you want to set a static address, make it on the 10.0.2.0/24 network with a gateway address of 10.0.2.2

Comment: *DHCP works* is hard to understand, if I don't set up anything, ping does not work at all, and program I try to install with pacman also fails. I will try 10.0.2.0.

Comment: something else is wrong then ... anyway, note the gateway should be 10.0.2.2 not 10.0.2.1 as I originally stated - see [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat)

Comment: if you don't mess with the arch install, what IP address does it get though

Comment: enps03 would have no IP address

Comment: seems like somethings broken, but that could be Virtual Box or the Arch install - never used Arch in my life, so not sure if it should be using DHCP out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/#:%7E:text=VirtualBox%20has%20a%20built-in%20DHCP%20server%20and%20NAT,for%20a%20VM%29.%20The%20network%20mask%20is%20255.255.255.0.) I have figured out how to do it successfully.

Simply edit `/etc/systemd/network/enp0s3.network`

```ini
[Match]
Name=enp0s3
[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=10.0.2.5/24
Gateway=10.0.2.2
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

And restart

```
$ systemctl restart systemd-networkd
$ systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

After that, ping successfully works! `pacman -Syu` also works.